# use files with my C# application with Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have a shared folder in 2 computers using Google Drive options.
I would like to access this folder via C# software from those 2 computers.

For example, I'd like to upload a SQL DB and be able to access and edit this DB from those 2 computers.

Is there a way for doing that?

Note:
it doesn't have to be SQL DB, 
it could be any file, even a text file (the SQL DB was just an example).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the samples in Google Driver API documents that link [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet#setting_up_this_sample_application)